# URL redirect without file extension

Tags: apache, redirect

I was trying to make "http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext" to "http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file" but failed

this is the code, that I was using. But it didn't work as I expected.
but didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/^/(.*)$ /^/^/$1.ext
```

thank you

Comment: Try: `^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ $1/$2/$3.ext` or something similar to that.

Comment: didn't work. when access http://sub.domain.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext